# ASP.NET Core Identity bad performance on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, npgsql

I'm running load tests on an aspnet core 3.0 API. The project is basically the default template with aspnet core identity. So I wasn't expecting these bad performances on /api/Account/Login:

```cs
 public class LogInController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        public LogInController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("/api/Account/Login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginViewModel model)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return BadRequest(result);
            }
            return Ok();
        }
}
```

I'm running the API on :

- 1 Pod on kubernetes(GCP)
- PostgreeSQL on GCP (vCPU: 4 | Ram: 15 GB | Hard Disk SSD:15 GB)
- AspentUser count: 3.387.988

The load test result:
[image]

Looking at the Postgres log the query response time is below 100 ms.

am I missing some kestrel or EF core configuration?  how many concurrent client  Aspnet core Identity can handle? I didn't find any benchmark about this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's Kuberents?

Comment: Did you manage to improve the performance? we are facing similar problem but we are using azure k8s instead

Comment: ah, it was a nice trip. The main problem was due to not having set [resource limits in the deployment.yml](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod). Once the limit was set the performance improved by a lot, we reached 8000 rpm. We still have a few calls above the second.  But the excessive latency is caused by the Nginx ingress. Rerunning the test with the Kubernetes Ingress all the request was under 100ms. @MichaelLam

Comment: Finally to reach our target of 16000 rpm we were forced to set 2 pods at startup. Running the test with more than 4000 rpm with a single pod saturated all the assigned CPU @MichaelLam